# What is a Riven Word™ / Phrase™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Riven Word™ or Phrase™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| RIVEN™ | UN-RIVEN™ |
| --- | --- |
| ROBE | COAT |
| AMZN | MSFT |
| GNAT | WASP |
| THUG | RUFFIAN |
| RAVINE | CREVICE |
| ANGER TAN | RAGE BURN |
| LIAR ENVY | TRUE LOVE |
| RINSER FAVE | AERIE CHURN |
| GENTRY LEG ART | COMMON ARM TAT |
| RAVER TANGERINE | RESERVED ORANGE |

CSV version:

```
RIVEN™,UN-RIVEN™
ROBE,COAT
AMZN,MSFT
GNAT,WASP
THUG,RUFFIAN
RAVINE,CREVICE
ANGER TAN,RAGE BURN
LIAR ENVY,TRUE LOVE
RINSER FAVE, AERIE CHURN
GENTRY LEG ART,COMMON ARM TAT
RAVER TANGERINE,RESERVED ORANGE
```

Comment: I smell anagrams ...

Comment: Tangerine Argentine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off, if you're reading this, please upvote TwoBitOperation's answer - he did a lot of legwork on this one that made me see the answer.

A Riven word can be defined as:

> Any word or phrase which, when ROT13'ed, the result is the same word or phrase, but backwards

Examples:

> ROBE = EBOR
>  ... but COAT = PBNG
>
>  AMZN = NZMA
>  ... but MSFT = ZFSG
>
>  RINSER FAVE = EVAFRE SNIR
>  ... but AERIE CHURN = NREVR PUHEA
>
>  RAVER TANGERINE = ENIRE GNATREVAR
>  ... but RESERVED ORANGE = ERFREIRQ BENATR

The reason that each of these words is called a Riven word/phrase is

> That "A RIVEN" itself is a Riven phrase:
>  A RIVEN = N EVIRA

Comment: Hooray! For imaginary bonus points, can you explain the title?

Comment: @whrrgarbl Just got it and updated the answer :)

Comment: Correct again :) The meaning of "split apart" was just a side effect, it was hard enough already to find sensible words / phrases.

Comment: Ah, this IS a lot more elegant than what I came up with.  I needed to keep working inwards from the ends of the word.

Answer (score 16):

For Riven words:

> The first pair of letters are the same distance apart in the alphabet as the last pair

EXAMPLES:

> ROBE:
> RO ->  O(PQ)R = 2
> BE -> B(CD)E = 2
>
> AMZN:
> AM -> A(BCDEFGHIJKL)M = 11
> ZN -> N(OPQRSTUVWXY)Z = 11
>
> GNAT:
> GN -> G(HIJKLM)N = 6
> AT -> T(UVWXYZ)A = 6
>
> THUG:
> TH -> H(IJKLMNOPQRS)T= 11
> UG -> G(HIJKLMNOPQR)S = 11
>
> RAVINE:
> RA: R(STUVWXYZ)A = 8 
> NE: E(FGHIJKLM)N = 8 
>
> LIAR ENVY:
> LI: I(JK)L = 2 
> VY: V(WX)Y = 2

COUNTER-EXAMPLE:

> COAT:
> CO ->  C(DEFGHIJKLMN)O = 11
> AT ->  T(UVWXYZ)A = 6  or
> AT ->  A(BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS)18 
>  **"COAT" is Un-Riven**

Comment: I bet you found this via AMZN.

Comment: Yes, that was the key.

Comment: So close! You are thinking along the right lines, but there is a simpler (and stricter) explanation.

Comment: @Joe exactly it! I will add a counterexample to show that vs. this

Comment: Honestly that probably should have been an answer, not a comment. Fixing that. Anyone reading this, upvote this answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but something I've noticed that might be significant:

> We can change the last letter of RIVEN to get RIVER. We can change the other RIVEN™ words and phrases in various ways to get river-related terms:
>
>  An anagram of ROBE is BORE, which is a kind of wave that travels upriver
>
>  A RAVINE is produced by a river (but a CREVICE is not)
>
>  Insert A and O in AMZN and you get AMAZON, which is a river
>
>  RAVER can also be transformed into RIVER by changing one letter. As greenturtle3141 has pointed out, TANGERINE is an anagram of ARGENTINE, but none of [the major Argentinian rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rivers_of_Argentina#Longest_Rivers) seem to fit anything here.

Comment: Liar Envy - swap L to R and anagram to Yin River, in Myanmar

Comment: MSFT (non-Riven) appears to be MISFIT, and the others are just synonyms/antonyms of the Riven word/phrase on the same row (eg. a ruffian is a thug, anger/rage and tan/burn)

Comment: Joe: the synonyms/antonyms thing is typical for this kind of puzzle. Good catch for LIAR ENVY, but it also requires the A to be changed to an I.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed! ... but you are barking up the wrong tree here. @Joe, the synonym/antonym thing was just a way to think of example non-riven words to put in the chart, and isn't actually relevant to the rule. As a small hint - it was a lot harder to make A Riven Word/Phrase than a non-riven one.