# What is a Breech Phrase™?

Tags: cipher, pattern, word-property

This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Breech Phrase™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| BREECH PHRASES | NOT BREECH PHRASES |
| --- | --- |
| UNFIT CROWD | INEPT HORDE |
| SLUG DRIP | WORM OOZE |
| DAWN VEIL | DUSK MASK |
| COCKY OASES | BRASH FONTS |
| HAD AXE | GOT SAW |
| HIDE POTS | BURY PANS |
| ONCE CALM | THEN COOL |
| WET DOG | DRY CAT |
| DUMB PAIR | MUTE TEAM |
| BOXED TUNER | CASED GIZMO |
| DATE TIPS | GIRL HINT |
| NEW AIR | OLD GAS |
| BIRD MARK | CROW SCAR |
| HER IVY | HIS GEM |
| WOMB PACK | VOID LOAD |
| DRY BUG | WET FLY |
| LIMP HEAD | HARD FOOT |
| ONYX NODE | INKY SITE |
| LAST BAIT | ONLY LURE |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
BREECH PHRASES, NOT BREECH PHRASES
UNFIT CROWD, INEPT HORDE
SLUG DRIP, WORM OOZE
DAWN VEIL, DUSK MASK
COCKY OASES, BRASH FONTS
HAD AXE, GOT SAW
HIDE POTS, BURY PANS
ONCE CALM, THEN COOL
WET DOG, DRY CAT
DUMB PAIR, MUTE TEAM
BOXED TUNER, CASED GIZMO
DATE TIPS, GIRL HINT
NEW AIR, OLD GAS
BIRD MARK, CROW SCAR
HER IVY, HIS GEM
WOMB PACK, VOID LOAD
DRY BUG, WET FLY
LIMP HEAD, HARD FOOT
ONYX NODE, INKY SITE
LAST BAIT, ONLY LURE
```

***Bonus Puzzle:***

> If a Breech Phrase™ possesses a certain property, then I call it a Twin Breech Phrase™. What is a Twin Breech Phrase™ and how many examples of it can you give?

Comment: Is the [tag:cipher] tag really applicable?

Comment: Isn't it? The property the phrases possess involves a cipher...

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but [Riven Words™](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43301/what-is-a-riven-word-phrase) are based on a very similar concept :)

Comment: @whrrgarbl Those are phrases, though.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Of course, I didn't mean to suggest they were exact duplicates. I just noticed that they are based on similar operations.

Comment: @whrrgarbl, yeah! A Riven Word is one half of what I ended up calling a Twin Breech Word. The longest I could come up with was "ravine" so kudos to you on those longer ones!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A Breech Phrase™ is one where

> The second word is the reverse of the rot-$n$ encrypted first word for some number $n$.

Examples

> If we apply the rot-9 cipher to UNFIT, we get DWORC which is CROWD backwards. 
>  If we apply the rot-23 cipher to SLUG, we get PIRD, which is DRIP backwards. 
>  If we apply the rot-16 cipher to COCKY, we get SESAO which is OASES backwards. 
>  If we apply the rot-16 cipher to BOXED, we get RENUT which is TUNER backwards. 
>  If we apply the rot-14 cipher to WOMB, we get KCAP which is PACK backwards. 
>  If we apply the rot-8 cipher to LAST, we get TIAB which is BAIT backwards.

Bonus Question

> My guess would be that a Twin Breech Phrase™ could use the same word twice. Obviously, every palindrome which is sufficiently grammatically flexible provides us with a trivial Twin Breech Phrase™ but we can also find some more: 
>  **rot-13** 
>  CHERUP CHERUP 
>  FANS FANS (which means *cools down the supporters via a wafting motion*) 
>  ROBE ROBE (which means *to wrap a robe in a robe*) 
>  REBORE REBORE (which means *to make a new wider boring out of one that already exists*)

Meaning of Breech

> One possibility, as pointed out by Dan Russell in the comments, is that this refers to a 'breech' birth - when a baby is born feet first, so reversed (and possibly rotated).

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any ideas about why they are called "Breech Phrases"?

Comment: A "breech" birth is one where the baby's feet come out first, so reversed (and possibly rotated as well).

Comment: Thanks @DanRussell. I was also thinking that a breech phrase has a pair of words, like a pair of breeches and that the words are somehow 'opposite' like left and right?

Comment: @hexomino That sounds reasonable too, though now my brain is going to a baby being born feet first *into* a pair of pants, or twins being born feet first, one into each leg of a pair of pants...

Comment: @DanRussell, you're on the right track with breech (or backwards) babies. How are these babies commonly delivered? That's the last dot to connect in explaining the name of the phrase.

Comment: If a fetus is found to be "breech", i.e. feet down in the uterus, an "external cephalic version" is usually attempted - that is, you try to rotate it to the normal head-down orientation.

Comment: I suspect that the explanation of "breech phrase" focuses wrongly on "reverse" and "rotate" instead of "reverse" and "Caesar chiphre" (which is the same as rot-n), alluding to the Caesarian section, that is commonly performed if rotating does not work.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher basically has it: A breech baby is *backwards* and is (commonly) delivered by *Caesarian section*. This clues the puzzler to *reverse* one of the words of the phrase and perform a *Caesar shift* on it (or vice versa).